# How to select line in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to figure out how to use Text Item Delimiters on a long line of text that is in a log file.

Within the log of information there is always a constant phrase that i'm searching for which leads me to the line of text. I'm getting to the line I want by searching for **"[Constant]"**, for example.

The problem I'm having is that I can't select the whole line to perform a Delimiter. Below is a very basic example of what the log looks like.

```
qwertyuiop
mnbvcxza
oqeryuiiop
[Constant] 1234567890123456-098765432109876-8765432118976543
odgnsgnsanfadf
joiergjdfmgadfs
```

Any advice would be appreciated.
So far I'm using:

```
repeat 16 times
key code 124 using (shift down)
end repeat
```

Which does the job fine but it is clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to find a line of text containing a specific string is the shell command `grep`.

```
set theConstant to "Constant"

set theText to "qwertyuiop
mnbvcxza
oqeryuiiop
Constant 1234567890123456-098765432109876-8765432118976543
odgnsgnsanfadf
joiergjdfmgadfs"

set foundLine to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theText & " | tr '\\r' '\\n' | grep " & quoted form of theConstant
```

the `tr` part to replace `return` (0x0d) characters with `linefeed` (0x0a) characters is necessary to conform to the shell line separator requirements.

If the constant contains special characters it's a bit more complicated, because you have to escape the characters before passing them to the shell.

```
set theConstant to "\\[Constant\\]"

set theText to "qwertyuiop
mnbvcxza
oqeryuiiop
[Constant] 1234567890123456-098765432109876-8765432118976543
odgnsgnsanfadf
joiergjdfmgadfs"

set foundLine to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theText & " | tr '\\r' '\\n' | grep " & quoted form of theConstant
```

If you want to read the text from a file on disk you can use this

```
set logFile to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Logs:myLogFile.log"
set theText to read file logFile as «class utf8»
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is puzzling. Do you want to parse a text/log file or a script to work with the GUI of some app? Because that is what your code suggests...

If you want to parse a log file, which is easier, you can use the good old Unix tools OSX comes with. You can use them from inside Applescript like this...

```
set logfile to "/some/path/file.log"

# Quote the string in case it contains spaces... or add single quotes above...
set qlogfile to quoted form of logfile

# Prepare the shell command to run
set cmd to "grep '^\\[Constant]' " & qlogfile & " | cut -c 12- | tr '-' '\\n'"

# Run it and capture the output
try
set cmdoutput to (do shell script cmd)
on error
   # Oh no, command errored. Best we do something there
end try
```

The result looks like this...

```
tell current application
    do shell script "grep '^\\[Constant]' '/some/path/file.log' | cut -c 12- | tr '-' '\\n'"
        --> "1234567890123456
098765432109876
8765432118976543"
end tell
Result:
"1234567890123456
098765432109876
8765432118976543"
```

So to break it down the shell commands are,

- `grep ... |` will read the contents of the file and select all lines that start `^` with the text `[Constant]` and pass what it finds `|` on to the next command
- `cut` cuts out the characters from position `12` until the end `-` of the line
- `tr` replaced any character `-` with `\n` which is the code for newline in unix.

The `\\` you see are due to having it executed from inside Applescript. You only need on if you run it inside Terminal.

If you care to know the contents of one line from the other, then remove the last command `| tr '-' '\\n'` and it will return

```
Result:
"1234567890123456-098765432109876-8765432118976543"
```